# <?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8”?> message appearing when using kableextra

Tags: r, rstudio

I am getting an unexpected message in my R presentation output.  I am moving to use kable and kableExtra.  When I attempt to render the following code:

````
  <div id="table1">
  <h5>Savings Summary</h5>
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
kable(prod_weekly_dept_rept) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", full_width = F, position= "left"))
##print(xtable(prod_weekly_dept_rept, digits=0), type="html", include.rownames=FALSE) 
```
  </div>
````

I am getting the following message in my output

[image: R presentation output]

It feels to me that I have missed something basic in my setup.  Anyone with younger eyes able to spot my error?

Comment: It's easier to help you when you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bikerjohn I removed the XML declaration sentence from the latest dev version of kableExtra. Thanks for raising it up.